# I can't put a custom sound in my notification

Tags: android, audio, kotlin

I'm making the notifications of my app, and I can't put a custom sound, I tried in many ways, and I notice that in Android 9 doesn't work, but in Android 7 it works fine

I tried with 
.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/" + R.raw.seatbelt ))

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val mChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
    }



    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
        .setContentTitle(body.getString("title"))
        .setContentText(body.getString("alert"))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(body.getString("alert")))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        val notification = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.packageName+"/raw/mysong.mp3")
        val r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification)
        r.play()
```

I have a Samsung Galaxy s8 with android 9 and the result is that always play the default sound notification, but I tried it on a Motorola with android 7 and it play my sound

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add sound to your `channel` using `AudioAttributes`

```
    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .build();
```

and add it to your channel like this :

```
    mChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
```

You may need uninstall the app to alter sound settings, Check out these [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels) for more details.